# Hibernate/Spring : Pessimist vs Optimist locking?

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

There's something I'm not sure to understand with locking and transaction while using an ORM tool like Hibernate (with Spring framework).

For example when you're using @Transactional and you're specifying an isolation level, does that mean you're using pessimist locking ?

Can you both use pessimist and optimist lock at the same time ?
I've heard optimist locking is generally better but I haven't found many project with @Version stuff etc...Most of the time I always see @Transaction Spring annotation being used to manage transactions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example when you're using @Transactional and you're specifying an isolation level, does that mean you're using pessimist locking ?

Not necessarily.

You can specify a method to do a *dirty reads* by specifying the isolation as `READ UNCOMMITTED` and if another transaction has modified but yet not committed the row your method is reading, you'll basically return the modified but not yet committed values.  This is because in this isolation level, no shared read locks are created at read time.  So in short, this method does a basic read without any concern with locking.

> Can you both use pessimist and optimist lock at the same time ?

Absolutely.

You can ask Hibernate to apply a pessimistic lock on an entity that contains `@Version` field if your use case dictates you need that behavior.

> I've heard optimist locking is generally better but I haven't found many project with @Version stuff etc...Most of the time I always see @Transaction Spring annotation being used to manage transactions.

I will say the web is full of trivial examples that do not take into account all of the intrinsic needs of data consistency in a complex application.  Those examples are meant to mainly illustrate that the following is preferred over its counterpart

```
@Transactional
public void doSomeSpecialThing() {
  // do your thing here
}
```

vs

```
public void doSomeSpecialThing() {
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  try {
    // do your thing here
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
  }
  catch ( Exception e ) {
    if ( entityManager.getTransaction().isActive() ) {
      entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Whether you need to apply pessimistic, optimistic, or a combination of both in your method's data access code becomes a use case specific need rather than a generalization.